# R Backports and Invalid Signature

Tags: r, linux, debian, signature

I run debian stable (bullseye) and I use the official R backports.
See

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

I added a line to mu repositories

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep r-project
deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/
```

And everything has been good until today.
Now, when I update, I get an error about the signature of the R repository when I run sudo apt update, see

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG FCAE2A0E115C3D8A Johannes Ranke (Wissenschaftlicher Berater) <johannes.ranke@jrwb.de>
W: Failed to fetch http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/bullseye-cran40/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG FCAE2A0E115C3D8A Johannes Ranke (Wissenschaftlicher Berater) <johannes.ranke@jrwb.de>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The signature has always been working until now.
I reimported it following the instructions here

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#administration-and-maintenance

which I paste below

```
You can fetch and import the current key using

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'

Note that you need to add sudo if you are not running this as root.

If this fails, it may be due to a firewall blocking port 11371. In this case, you can search for 0xE19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF at https://keyserver.ubuntu.com, and copy the key block shown when klicking on the link in the line starting with pub into a plain text file, named, for instance, jranke.asc which you add to apt with (sudo) apt-key add jranke.asc.
```

but it does not work.
I import the signature, but when I update I am always told it is not valid.
Anyone else is experiencing the same? Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I am facing similar problem for 'buster-cran35' repo. Anyone know if it is also going to be fixed ?

Answer (score 12):

Same Problem.
The reason: I contacted Mr. Ranke and he wrote that he failed to update the key in a timely manner.
I expect it will be fixed soon.

**UPDATE: new keys are avalible now.**

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key '95C0FAF38DB3CCAD0C080A7BDC78B2DDEABC47B7'
```

Comment: Do you have any sense of what "soon" means? Hours? Days? Weeks?

Comment: Sadly no. All i got it the cause of the problem but i suspect since Mr. Ranke is aware of the problem, he will fix it.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks though!

Comment: It's done: It is now :)

Answer (score 3):

Until "soon" becomes "now" you can use this workaround:

Update your: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list with:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/
```

Do this before running apt-get update. Remember to revoke this change after key is updated as this is not safe solution.

Comment: This created a conflict for me. Instead I edited /etc/apt/sources.list the same way, adding  `[trusted=yes]`.

Comment: Weird. Even by doing the same, I still get the same error about the signature and the repository not being updated.

Comment: @larry77 see my answer. New key is available now.

Comment: Ops...I did not notice your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

After running

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key '95C0FAF38DB3CCAD0C080A7BDC78B2DDEABC47B7'
```

The problem has disappeared for me.